# A non-degenerate region error in DiscretizeRegion

Tags: regions, discretization

Consider the following region:

```
Vol1 = Parallelepiped[{-4.75, -1.25, 
    14.5}, {{3.35, 0, 0}, {0, 2.5, 0}, {0, 0, 12}}];
Vol2 = Parallelepiped[{-4.75, -1.25, 
    14.5 + 12}, {{2.5, 0, 0}, {0, 2.5, 0}, {0, 0, 7}}];
Vol = RegionUnion[Vol1, Vol2];
```

It is just a merging of two parallelepipeds.

When trying to discretize the region `Vol`, I get the following error:

```
DiscretizeRegion[Vol]
```

> DiscretizeRegion::regpnd: A non-degenerate region is expected at
> position 1 of DiscretizeRegion[Polyhedron[Number of points: 14 Number
> of faces: 11]].

The error is present on 12.1 but not on 13.XX. Could you please tell me how to remove this error?

Comment: No error in 12.3 (Windows) or 13.3 (Cloud). Which version are you using? Have you tried with `vol1 = Rationalize@Parallelepiped[...]`?

Comment: No error in version 13.2 Windows

Comment: @DanielHuber : sorry, the version is 12.1. I will add the information.

Comment: No error in version 13.3.0 Windows 10

Comment: @MariuszIwaniuk : the problem is present for Mathematica 12.1.

Comment: @JohnTaylor, have you tried my suggestion with `Rationalize`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`BoundaryDiscretizeRegion` the region before `RegionUnion`.

```
$Version
(* "11.3.0 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (March 27, 2018)" *)
RegionUnion[BoundaryDiscretizeRegion@Vol1, 
 BoundaryDiscretizeRegion@Vol2]
```

[image]